# Migration from MarketingCloudSDK v4.9.7 to v5.1.1

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios

We are migrating our iOS project from MarketingCloudSDK v4.9.7 to v5.1.1. I am aware about the [initial setup](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/) document but facing difficulties to migrate the project just on the bases of that.

Could you please navigation to (v5.1.1) migration document (if available )or any other document which gives overall information about the framework.

Comment: Is there a specific area of difficulty you're running up against? Most of the SDK's API has very close mappings from old to new (subscriberKey->contactKey, tags, attributes, etc.) and the layout of the headers in the new framework help to delineate feature areas. Please let us know where you're running into a struggle; we'll be glad to help (and find areas to improve our docs).

Comment: Hi Brian, Thanks for your reply. I am not able to find alternate method for bellow 1. shouldDisplayAlertViewIfPushReceived 2.  updateET (I guess 'sfmc_refresh(fetchCompletionHandler: nil)' alternative for it. please conform.)

Comment: For `shouldDisplay...` use UNUserNotification's willPresentNotification method - that is system-designed to handle notifications while app is in foreground. For `updateET` there is no replacement, as the usage requirements for that method has been addressed within the SDK.